# mod rewrite, string instead of numerical value in the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to rewrite mods so that instead of http://company.com/page.php?title=about I could have http://www.company.com/about

Now I know how to change the url for the numerical value
e.g.
company.com/page.php?id=2 I could have company.com/2

This can be done by rewriting .htaccess:
RewriteRule    ^([0-9]+)/?$    page.php?title=$1    [NC,L]

Now how can i achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to tweak your regex to allow alpha-numerics:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ page.php?title=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```